# Ansible list flatten

Tags: list, ansible

I have the following list in Ansible and would like to get a flat structure.
Input:

```
[
{
  id: "one",
  level: "3"
},
{
  id: "two",
  level: "8"
},
...
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
{
  one: "3"
},
{
  two: "8"
},
...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way out of the box.

You can either use custom [template filter](https://github.com/berlic/devopsdays-ansible/blob/master/filter_plugins/template.py):

```
my_list | map('template','{"<<item.id>>":"<<item.level>>"}',from_json=true) | list
```

Or generate new variable with `set_fact` + `register` + `with_items`, see [Process complex variables with set_fact and with_items](https://ansibledaily.com/process-complex-variables-with-set_fact-and-with_items/).

```
- set_fact:
    tmp_item: '{ "{{ item.id }}": "{{ item.level }}" }'
  with_items: "{{ my_list }}"
  register: tmp_list
- debug:
    msg: "{{ tmp_list.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.tmp_item') | list }}"
```